# How can I switch to new tab on open?

Tags: opera

How do I force Opera to switch over to the tab I opened when I click on 'Open in new tab'?  (I am opening a new tab because I want to see the content - opening it without switching to it seems useless to me)

Comment: On the latest Opera for windows, when I press ctrl N it opens and switch to the newly created tab. How do you open a new tab? Note: New Tab in opera defaults to their "Speed Dial" page.

Answer (score 3):

The "old" Opera (Presto, up to version 12.x) switches to new tabs by default and gives you the option (context menu for links) to both "open in new tab" and "open in background tab", so I'm guessing you mean the newer version of Opera (Blink, version 15+).

While playing around with and customising these sorts of settings was a breeze in the old version, the new one requires you to install extensions. You could try the [Classic Tabs](https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/classic-tabs/) extension to bring back some of Opera 12's tab options, or, if that's not to your liking, use the [Download Chrome Extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/) which lets you install Chrome extensions in Opera, and then try [Tab Activate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-activate/jlmadbnpnnolpaljadgakjilggigioaj) or [Tabs to the front](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-to-the-front/hjaooagfdhdhmbfchnkhggjmacjlacla).

Comment: +1 The new, Webkit-based Opera is pretty good, but it's still missing lot of features I used in the old version.

Comment: @boot13: Agreed, and it's looking more and more as though it will never get back to being what it once was - an ultra-configurable browser aimed squarely at power users. The new browser on the block taking over that role is [Vivaldi](http://vivaldi.com). Former Opera employees are [very actively developing it](https://vivaldi.net/blogs/teamblog/), and though it's still a long way from being ready for the masses, I've started using it as my main browser and am loving the progress each week.

Answer (score 0):

Tried extension "New Tab Start Page". After install click on extension. A list will appear. click " Configure extension". Once there another list will appear: click yes to first 6. At the top, add chosen URL into the "Custom URL" bar. Make certain you scroll down to save.